# How to do Event delegation for an Array?(or NodeList)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parameters, event-delegation

I'm trying to use the Event delegation/switch statement for the first time in my life, and I'm having trouble with for loop. When it was 'array[i]' it wasn't a problem. But now I'm removing the for loop to use the event delegation and putting it inside of a function, it keeps giving me errors, and I don't know what parameter can replace (and make the code work again) that array[i] in the new function. Any help or explanation will be appreciated.

```
//original code

const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (display.value.length < 13) {
      return;
    }
    if (display.value == "0" && numbers[i] != dot) {
      display.value = numbers[i].innerText;
      calculation = display.value;
    } else {
      if (numbers[i] == dot && display.value.includes(".")) {
        return;
      } else if (numbers[i] == dot && display.value == "") {
        return;
      } else {
        display.value += numbers[i].innerText;
        calculation = display.value;
      }
    }

    buttonEffect(numbers[i], "number-active");
  });
}
```

```
// New code

const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

function numberClick(number) {
  if (display.value.length > 13) {
    return;
  }
  if (display.value == "0" && this != dot) {
    display.value = number.innerText;
    calculation = display.value;
  } else {
    if (numbers == dot && display.value.includes(".")) {
      return;
    } else if (number == dot && display.value == "") {
      return;
    } else {
      display.value += number.innerText;
      calculation = display.value;
    }
  }
  operatorOnOff = false;
  buttonEffect(number, "number-active");
}




document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  switch (e.target.dataset.key) {
    case "number":
      numberClick();
      break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the element that was the target of the click into `numberClick` and use it where previously you used `numbers[i]`. It looks like you're already doing the second part of that, and you even have a parameter declared for it, you just need to pass the element in:

```
numberClick(e.target);
```

Note that if your `.number` elements have child elements, `target` may be one of those child elements rather than `.number`. To handle that, you can use the DOM's relatively-new [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method, probably combined with `contains` to make sure it didn't match something surrounding `.wrapper`:

```
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const number = e.target.closest(".number");
    if (number && this.contains(number) && number.dataset.key) {
        numberClick(number);
    }
});
```

There are polyfills you can use if you need to support obsolete browsers, or just do the loop yourself:

```
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let number = e.target;
    while (number && !number.matches(".number")) {
        if (this === number) {
            return; // Reached the wrapper without finding it
        }
        number = number.parentElement;
    }
    if (number && number.dataset.key) {
        numberClick(number);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't believe that the solution was that easy... You got me with the first line of the code. Thank you very much!!!! You saved me.